# Bordering towered airspaces

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, usa, radio-communications

I'm looking for guidance on radio communications when taking off from Delta airspace and flying into Charlie that starts where the Delta ends. My aircraft can only monitor one frequency at a time. Can I just tell the Delta tower I'm flying into Charlie and request a frequency change while still in Delta in order to establish comms with Charlie tower before entering Charlie airspace? If so what would be the preferred phraseology?

Comment: Can we assume that the Delta airport is the same one served by the Charlie, or is it an outlying adjacent airfield?  And what country?  (*please consider tagging US and/or FAA*)

Comment: Outlying adjacent airfield in the US. Delta is KTTD and Charlie is KPDX.

Comment: @mandela008 TTD can get you cleared into the Charlie if you're headed that way. And "request frequency change" is the standard phraseology to get handed off even before you leave the delta attitude. You should know the approach frequency and have it loaded already in the standby. Hope you're enjoying the wind and the hillside on the left downwind 25!

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the class D tower will tell you you to when to change frequencies and it will most likely be to the class C's approach control, not their tower. You will hear something like, "Nxxxx, contact Class C approach on 123.45" and you can respond and change frequencies at that point. You still have to follow the rules for entering class C airspace.